# How to use media query for changing the size of a Chiclets?

Tags: media-queries

I'm trying to adjust my chiclet's on my website using media queries so when someone's viewing the site on mobile, they'll become smaller. But the only way I seem to be able to change its size is in the HTML portion of the site with this portion of the code:

"fa fa-twitter fa-4x icon-3d">

But I'm not sure how to make it so it's only changed in size due to a certain screen size. 
If anyone has any idea how to do this I would love to know. Thanks.

Here's a link to my site if it helps: https://www.tamaricampbell.com/Desultorycontactpage.html

Comment: What's a chiclet? An image? Icon? It's helpful to post your relevant code. You can try using font-size or scaling it down with `transform`.

Comment: A social media chiclet, I should've put, is an icon of a social media - like Facebook - put onto a website that leads to your social media page. Here's the full code. I thought I put it in, lol.  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tamaralee.campbell"<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x icon-3d"></i></a> </th></center>

Comment: I tried the transform and it's only affecting the circle, not the logo.

Comment: I see, I've never heard that term.  Not sure what the circle is you're talking about.  If you provide a reproducible example to mess with that would help. Edit: If you apply the transform to the `<a>` it'll scale it all.  Also, you're missing a closing `>` on those anchors... might want to run your markup through an HTML validator to check for those.

Comment: Sorry, I took so long. I'm not sure how to add the files so you can work with the html, any suggestions.

Comment: Currently your anchor tags look like `<a href="..." <i class=".."></a>` which isn't valid HTML. Also, did you apply the transform to the `<a>` tag instead of the `<i>`?

Comment: I made the transform too large the first time I tried it. It's working perfectly now. Thanks. Also, if what you mentioned above isn't valid HTML what should I use instead?

Comment: You need to close the `<a>` tag before adding the `<i>` as a child, as well as closing the `<i>` tag:  `<a href="..."><i class="..."></i></a>`

Comment: Sorry for the long reply. I'll try that. Thank you.